# Installing Debian packages from Stretch DVD 2 and 3 after installation using apt?

Tags: debian, apt

Can I install Debian packages from Stretch DVD 2 and 3 after installation using apt? Because installing on VM, it didn't detect the second and the third DVD.

Comment: Note to reviewers: this isn’t a duplicate of [the previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/512928/86440); this is about installing packages from DVDs after installation, the previous question is about installing packages from DVDs during installation.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks for clearing that up. I'm very new to Linux. I'm sizing it up to see if I can buy a harddrive and install use it as my main operating system, and downgrade Windows to my secondary operating system. I want to use Linux because I do two things mainly: Web dev, and vision/graphics. Windows has better Vision/graphics tools (also, Visual Studio) but Linux has better web dev tools. Thanks.

Comment: @GAD3R That was about detecting the DVD "during" the installation. This is about using apt to install them "after" it's been all set up. I have added the images to my hypervisor, I just need a guide to install them from a DVD. I couldn't find anything that related to Debian. Sorry if this is a common question.

Comment: @GAD3R the two questions are different and have value separately IMO. The answers would be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
apt-cdrom add
```

as root (or using `sudo`), and follow the prompts – it will ask you to insert a disk, then scan it and add the relevant information to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You will then be able to install packages from it as usual.

Answer (score 3):

In your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you will have an entry like this for the first DVD after installation:

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 "Stretch" - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190216-11:59]/ stretch contrib main
```

This line is used to tell apt to use the cdrom as a package source.
The second and third DVD should be "Binary-2" and "Binary-3". The complete string can be found on the DVD in the file `.disk/info`.

If you only have the ISO files and no (virtual) optical drive is available, 
you can mount the images manually and add a `deb file:` source to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

See [How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM Repository?](https://askubuntu.com/a/333620)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I can't edit this file, I can't login as root. What should I do? Online solutions say to use sudo but sudo opens the file in terminal, and doesn't let me save.

Comment: Use `su` or `su -` in terminal, then edit the file with your favourite editor.