# Debian cannot recognize Ethernet card B550M during installation

Tags: debian, system-installation, desktop, debian-installer

My system consists of a [B550M AORUS PRO-P motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550M-AORUS-PRO-P-rev-10#kf). I tried installing Debian Desktop 10.6 as a dual boot, but during the installation it doesn't recognize my Ethernet card.

I couldn't find the correct driver in the list during installation, so I choose for the option "none of the above". Then I was asked to place a removable device with the correct driver and so I did, but without luck. This is what I did: I downloaded the [2.5G Ethernet LINUX driver r8125 for kernel up to 5.6](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) and placed the software unpacked on a FAT formatted USB. I placed the USB in the system and moved on to the next step of the installation process. Unfortunately I received a message the system didn't recognize the removable device (or it just didn't recognize the software as a legit driver). Does the Debian installation need a .deb installation file of the driver?

I even tried the [nonfree edition](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.6.0+nonfree/amd64/bt-cd/) without success: Same error.

I was forced to continue the installation without a functional network driver, but now I need to configure and install everything by hand. I rather re-install Debian with the correct driver so Gnome etc. is all correctly installed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should have downloaded `r8125-9.004.01.tar.bz2` which you need to unpack and install:

```
tar xf r8125-9.004.01.tar.bz2
cd r8125-9.004.01
sudo ./autorun.sh
```

In order to be able to do that you need to **first** have kernel development headers installed as well as make and gcc.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way to provide the drivers during installation, so the installation process is able to setup the desktop environment and everything right up, from the start? Because I can't use apt-get because I have no connection to the internet at all

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512940/installing-debian-packages-from-stretch-dvd-2-and-3-after-installation-using-apt

Proceed to install the desired packages